# mongo listfield to postgreSQL fileds

Tags: django, postgresql, scrapy

I use scrapy and django with mongodb
scrapy has an `image_urls` and `images` is `dictionary`
so I save it as `Listfield`  in mongodb
and now I need to change the database form mongodb to postgreSQL  because we have to use amazon RDS in the future
But I don't know how to edit my model field.
Is it right to use foreignkey()
Please guide me.   Thank you

```
class Apple(models.Model):
    link        = models.URLField(max_length=255)       
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)               
    date        = models.CharField(max_length=100)          
    # image_urls  = ListField()        #mongo                 
    # images      = ListField()        #mongo


class Image(models.Model):
    image_urls  = models.ForeignKey(Apple)     
    images      = ListField()      #another foreign foreign key??
```